# How to make HTTP GET request in Rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I want to make a get request to url in rego. But it raises **Invalid parameter: unallowed built-in function call in rego module: http.send** error
Here is my code.

```
package play

default hello = false

hello {
    response := http.send({
        "method" : "GET",
        "url": "http://localhost:8181/v1/data/example"
    })
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That example is correct however https://play.openpolicyagent.org does not permit the `http.send` function for security reasons. Try it locally.

```
$ opa run
```

Inside the REPL:

```
> http.send({"method": "get", "url": "https://example.com"})
{
  "body": null,
  "raw_body": "\u003c!doctype html\u003e\n\u003chtml\u003e\n\u003chead\u003e\n    \u003ctitle\u003eExample Domain\u003c/title\u003e\n\n    \u003cmeta charset=\"utf-8\" /\u003e\n    \u003cmeta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /\u003e\n    \u003cmeta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" /\u003e\n    \u003cstyle type=\"text/css\"\u003e\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, \"Segoe UI\", \"Open Sans\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 2em;\n        background-color: #fdfdff;\n        border-radius: 0.5em;\n        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        div {\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            width: auto;\n        }\n    }\n    \u003c/style\u003e    \n\u003c/head\u003e\n\n\u003cbody\u003e\n\u003cdiv\u003e\n    \u003ch1\u003eExample Domain\u003c/h1\u003e\n    \u003cp\u003eThis domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.\u003c/p\u003e\n    \u003cp\u003e\u003ca href=\"https://www.iana.org/domains/example\"\u003eMore information...\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003c/div\u003e\n\u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e\n",
  "status": "200 OK",
  "status_code": 200
}
```

Comment: On version 0.30.1, I'm getting:    > http.send({"method": "get", "url": "https://example.com"})
undefined       <-- seems no call is being made. Does this work with http proxy? How can I see some debug message with the cause?

Comment: on powershell using $env:http_proxy = "proxy.org:8080" fixes the issue

Comment: If you enable strict errors you can see the cause. Type `strict-builtin-errors` inside the REPL and then re-run the command. You can do the same via the `opa eval` subcommand and the HTTP API as well.